# Displaying hint in an empty fragment for new accounts

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, design-patterns

[image]i want to display some sort of start up guide or hint in my fragments for new users when they log in for the first time and the fragment is empty. i have been searching all day for this but haven't found any yet. something like this

Comment: You're not finding anything because from *your* perspective the job is to hide the current view and show a different one, using `android:visibility="` or `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and stuff.

Comment: please describe more detailed what you want to achieve.